# Auf das/dem Konto eingehen

Tags: grammatical-case, article

Was ist richtig: *auf das Konto eingehen* oder *auf dem Konto eingehen*?

Ich habe verschiedene Sätze als Beispiele gefunden, aber es ist mal so, mal so, z.B.:

> Falls der Betrag nicht am Tag nach Fristablauf auf **dem** Konto eingegangen ist, wird die Buchung automatisch storniert
>
> Falls die Überweisung nicht innerhalb der 48-Stunden-Frist erfolgt oder das Geld nicht auf **das** Konto eingeht, teilt VonBest dem Kunden per E-Mail die Stornierung der Bestellung mit.

Comment: Die Grußformel am Schluss war sicher nett gemeint, ist hier aber nicht üblich.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generell ist es so: Auf + Dativ drückt einen Zustand aus, auf + Akkusativ eine Bewegung.

Im Fall von

> Das Geld ist auf dem Konto eingegangen.

wäre "Das Geld ist auf das Konto eingegangen" auch möglich gewesen. Für diese Variante spricht, dass "eingehen" eine Bewegung ausdrückt. Vielleicht gibt es sogar Leute, die diese Form für die einzig korrekte halten. Der Dativ betont hier allerdings die Tatsache, dass das Geld sich jetzt auf dem Konto befindet.

Dagegen bei

> Falls das Geld nicht auf das Konto eingeht, ...

betont der Akkusativ die Tatsache, dass das Geld auf das Konto gelangen soll.

Answer (score 3):

> Sie ging auf seinen Vorschlag ein.
>
> Sie ging auf das Kind ein.

*Auf Akk. eingehen* bedeutet *Akk. gedanklich folgen, sich zuwenden*.

> Der Brief ging im Büro ein.

*Im Dat. eingehen* bedeutet *ankommen*.

Mit dem Geld ist es wie mit dem Brief. Es kommt an. Allerdings kann man nicht "im Konto" sagen. Es ist immer *auf dem Konto*, weil ein Konto ja nur ein Eintrag auf der Seite eines Kassenbuches ist. Das angekommene Geld wird *aufgeschrieben*, nicht *eingeschrieben*.

In der Praxis ist der Gebrauch schwankend.

> Das Geld ging auf das Konto ein.
>
> Das Geld ging auf dem Konto ein.

Beides gebräuchlich. Ich würde eher Dativ verwenden, weil *eingehen auf* wie ganz oben geschrieben in jedem anderen Kontext *gedanklich folgen, sich zuwenden* bedeutet.