# speichern auf (+ Dat oder +Akk)?

Tags: grammatical-case, wechselpraeposition

Welche Variante ist richtig?

> A) Bitte speichere das Backup auf den USB-Stick.

oder

> B) Bitte speichere das Backup auf dem USB-Stick.

**Idee:** *Auf* ist eine lokale Präposition (Kategorie: Wechselpräposition). Da sich die Daten (nämlich das Backup vom Computer auf das Ziel zu bewegen sollen (nämlich zum USB-Stick), findet eine Bewegung zum Ziel (USB-Stick) statt. Die Daten wandern elektronisch.

Zu dieser Überlegung würde Vairante A) passen. Aber stimmt das wirklich? Oder geht gar beides? Und wenn B) richtig ist, weshalb?

Comment: Also auf "duden.de" steht das Beispiel im Dativ. Allerdings scheint das Wort "speichern" so neu zu sein, dass es noch beide Varianten gibt. In einigen Fällen ist es übrigens so, dass sich beide Varianten dauerhaft halten - z.B. je nach Region.

Comment: Gute Frage! Ich fürchte das *auf* allein bringt keine Klarheit! Vgl. ‚Ich deponiere es auf dem Dachboden‘, aber ‚ich bringe es auf den Müll‘! Ich kenne nur die Form mit Dativ, finde aber auch Akkusativ vertretbar.

Comment: Ich möchte auch eine differenzierte Verwendung je nach Nuance nicht ausschließen. Vgl. https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/38499/auf-das-dem-konto-eingehen?rq=1

Comment: @MartinRosenau Dazu muss eine Begrifflichkeit nicht "neu" sein - *lagern*, *ablegen* und *fahren* funktionieren ebenfalls mit beiden Fällen, wie viele andere Verben.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die Frage betrifft die Unterscheidung von *auf* als direktiver (mit dem Akkusativ) und *auf* als lokaler Präposition (mit dem Dativ). Grundsätzlich gilt (Grammis, [Differenzierung zwischen lokalen und direktiven Präpositionen](http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/sysgram.ansicht?v_typ=d&v_id=1448)):

> Lokative
>   Präpositionalphrasen denotieren bei Rektion des Dativs ein
>   "bestehendes", das heißt für den gesamten Ereigniszeitraum gültiges
>   Verhältnis, bei Rektion des Akkusativs ein "entstehendes", das heißt
>   nur für ein Teilintervall gültiges Verhältnis.

Zum Präpositionsgebrauch speziell bei "speichern" lassen sich bei einer kurzen Korpusrecherche mit COSMAS II (W-öffentlich) beide Formen ausgiebig nachweisen, wobei nach meinem Eindruck die Akkusativrektion überwiegt. Auch Müller, Wörterbuch deutscher Präpositionen, Bd. 2, 2012, S. 1788, verzeichnet im Eintrag zu "speichern" beide Formen:

> auf 1. jemand speichert etwas (Akk) auf etwas (Substantiv
>   im Dat. – nennt den Zustand „wo?“ oder Akk. –
>   nennt den Vorgang „wohin?“) *jemand legt etwas auf
>   dem Genannten ab, bringt es auf das Genannte, deponiert
>   es da*: etwas auf den Rechner, auf dem Mobiltelefon, auf
>   DVD, auf CD oder DVD, auf Rohlingen, auf dem
>   MP3-Player speichern; [...]

Auf das konkrete Beispiel in der Frage zurückkommend, lässt sich zugunsten der Akkusativrektion wie folgt argumentieren: Die Handlung "das Backup auf [den/dem] USB-Stick speichern" lokalisiert das Backup in der "auf"-Region des USB-Sticks erst nach Abschluss einer (resultativen) Handlung "speichern". Das Backup ist mithin nicht über die Gesamtdauer der Handlung ("speichern") auf dem USB-Stick lokalisiert, sondern erst nach deren Abschluss. Die Verwendung ist also direktiv. (Ich persönlich würde diese Variante vorziehen.)

Jedoch:

1. Es gibt Verwendungen, bei denen das Verb klar lokal-statischen Charakter hat. Beispiel: "Wir sind gesetzlich verpflichtet, Ihre Daten auf unseren Servern dauerhaft zu speichern." In dieser Verwendung kommt nur Dativ in Frage. Gar ausschließlich ein solches Verständnis herrscht im Universalduden (8. Aufl. 2015 via Munzinger) vor, der "speichern" als "(Daten) in einem elektronischen Speicher aufbewahren" definiert und folgerichtig im einzigen Beispiel den Dativ verwendet ("Daten [auf einer CD, auf der Festplatte] speichern."). Das Beispiel in der Frage zeigt sich bei genauer Betrachtung offen für eine solche Interpretation: "Bitte speichere das Backup auf dem USB-Stick" i.S.v. "Bitte bewahre das Backup auf dem USB-Stick auf".
2. Die Transformativität ist allgemein vergleichsweise schwach. Wenn man, wie Müller vorschlägt, "speichern" als "*ab*legen" (meine Hervorhebung) der Datei auffasst, weist dies darauf, dass auch hier teilweise schon die Endphase bzw. gar der Abschluss der genuin transformativen Handlung in das Wort "hineingelesen" wird (wie dies eben die Funktion der *ab*-Bildungen ist). Das zehrt aber gerade am Entstehungscharakter der Lokalisierungsrelation.

Soweit ein paar weiterführende Gedanken dazu. Die Antwort auf die konkrete Frage ist derweil schlicht: Beides ist gebräuchlich.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitiv hätte ich den Akkusativ vermutet. Du speicherst auf den USB-Stick, schiebst also die Dateien dorthin.

Andererseits ist mir nach kurzem Nachdenken klar geworden, dass der Dativ auch geht. Das würde weniger den Zielort des Backups als das Ergebnis des Vorgangs hervorheben.